# Using Advanced Custom Fields Gallery with Media Categories and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, gallery

**Question: I have created a gallery using Advanced Custom Fields. All the images I have added into the gallery I have given a custom taxonomy (category) e.g. 'Fashion', 'Portraits' etc. I have listed all the terms above the gallery. I want to be able to click a term, e.g. Fashion, and for all the images with the term 'Fashion' to load in the image container below. Similar to https://demo.kaliumtheme.com/photography/. I am stuck with getting the images to load on the click of a term. Can you help?**

Here's the code for the gallery:

```
        <?php $images = get_field('gallery');

        if( $images ): ?>
            <ul><div class="image__sizer"></div>
                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): $link = get_field('link', $image['ID']); ?>
                <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $image['ID'], 'category_media' ); ?>
                <?php if ( !empty( $terms ) ) : $term = array_shift( $terms ); ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>">
                        <div data-200-bottom="top: 0px;opacity:0%;" data--200-top="top:-250px;opacity:100%;" class="image__wrap">
                        <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                             <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <div class="image__meta">
                            <span><?php echo $term->name; ?> - <?php echo $image['title']; ?></span> 
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The custom taxonomy is called 'category_media'. I was looking to use a function like this one below:

```
 function prefix_load_term_posts () {
    $term_id = $_POST[ 'term' ];
        $args = array (
        'term' => $term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
             'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'category_media',
                  'field'    => 'id',
                  'terms'    => $term_id,
                  'operator' => 'IN'
                  )
              )
         );

    global $post;
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    ob_start ();  ?>

    <?php foreach ($myposts as $post):
    echo $images = get_field('gallery', $post->ID); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

   <?php wp_reset_postdata(); 
   $response = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   echo $response;
   die(1);
    }
```

with this JQuery function:

```
<script>
function term_ajax_get(termID) {
jQuery("a.ajax").removeClass("current");
jQuery("a.ajax").addClass("current"); //adds class current to the category menu item being displayed so you can style it with css
jQuery('.image-container ul li').fadeOut();
jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); //must echo it ?>';
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {"action": "load-filter2", term: termID },
    success: function(response) {
        jQuery(".image-container ul").html(response);
        return false;
    }
});
}
</script>
```

However, no images are loading into the container. Can anyone help and tell me what I'm missing? It would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not understood
Try to give more details and shorten the code
Do not let all the code give you just where you have a specific problem